# Managing windows updates via Batch file

Tags: batch, automation, windows-update, windows-server-2012

I have an instance of windows server 2012 and I am trying to get an idea of how to accomplish the following requirements via a batch file.

- Turn Windows Update to manual
- Change Import Updates to the option of “Check for updates but let me
  choose whether to download and install them”
- Enable the Microsoft Update: Give me updates for other Microsoft
  products when I updated Windows.

Is this possible or am I relegated to doing a majority of these steps manually. I know I can set the windows update service to manual(I think?!) via the following:

`sc config wuauserv start= demand`

I believe that I can solve the issues presented in the first, and the second bullet by using the following registry modifications from a bat file.

```
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU /v NoAutoUpdate /t Reg_DWORD /d 1
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU /v AUOptions /t Reg_DWORD /d 2
```

Comment: Perhaps use group/local polices instead. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328010

Comment: I have made edits to the above question after reading the article posted by @techie007.  I have still found no solution to the issue presented in bullet 3.

Comment: You'll need a script for #3: http://blogs.technet.com/b/danbuche/archive/2010/01/07/enabling-and-disabling-microsoft-update-in-windows-7-via-script.aspx

Comment: Yes I had just seen a few solutions similar to that one @techie007, I am about to head off for lunch but I am reading more about group policies right now as we don't currently use them but it is possible to possibly implement them.  Thank you for the info so far, I will check back.